# add a specific slide to a powerpoint array of slides

Tags: arrays, vba, powerpoint

The following command deletes at once an array of slides from a presentation:

```
ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1, 5, 69, 70.....)).delete
```

But how do I add a specific slide to the array (if the slide meet some condition) before proceeding to deletion?

Answer (score 2):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slides.range%28v=office.14%29.aspx), the parameter sent to the Range function can be an Integer index, a String slide name, or an Array of Integers and Strings. If you wish to use a SlideRange to perform your delete, you can define the array first, add whatever slides you wish by name or index number and then load the SlideRange and perform the delete:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim arrSlides() As Variant
    arrSlides = Array(1, 2, 69, 70)

    'Put this next part in a loop to continue adding more slides
    ReDim Preserve arrSlides(UBound(arrSlides) + 1)
    arrSlides(4) = 83  ' or "Name Of Slide"

    Application.ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(arrSlides).Delete
End Sub
```

---

**Alternative Solution**

If your goal is to delete slides that match a specific criteria, it's probably easier just to iterate through them all and delete them. This way you have greater freedom to test the specific properties of each individual slide.

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim tempSlide As Slide
    For Each tempSlide In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
        If tempSlide.Shapes.Count > 3 Then 'Or whatever your condition actually is
            tempSlide.Delete
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Both solutions are perfect.Thanks